# Classloader-Leak with Spring and Log4j2

Tags: spring, memory-leaks, log4j, log4j2

I am facing a classloader leak which I was able to repoduce it in a small project with only two classes and a few lines of code. It occurs as soon as a logger (Log4j2) is used.

**Problem:**
When deploying the application multiple times, the classes get loaded again and again until the PermGen space reaches its limit. [image: See screenshot from JVisualVM]

**Steps to reproduce:**
[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3f56x2y24vlv3v/memoryleak.zip?dl=0) this small Maven-Project containing two classes. They are also depicted below.

- Deploy application on a standard tomcat 7
- Start jvisualvm and monitor the tomcat instance
- Undeploy the application
- Deploy the application again... even if you hit the 'perform gc' button, the classes will not be removed.

**What I already tried without success:**

- Using the logger in a non-static field
- Starting the VM with "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
- Defining the logger in a Spring bean

Do you have any ideas, how to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code contained in the project referenced above:

*SpringContextInitializer.java* (based on 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

```
public class SpringContextInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addListener(new Log4jServletContextListener());
    servletContext.setAttribute("isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled", false);
    servletContext.setAttribute("log4jConfiguration", "classpath:log4j2.xml");

    // Load a spring context and manage the lifecycle of the root
    // application context
    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    appContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
    // Enable the use of a session scope
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());

}

}
```

*SpringConfiguration.java*

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SpringConfiguration.class.getName());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of [known memory leak issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20LOG4J2%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%202.5%20AND%20text%20~%20%22leak%22) with log4j version 2.4 and 2.4.1. The upcoming version log4j-2.5 will address all of these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is solved with the latest 2.5-SNAPSHOT version.